# Search for symbols in tags from multiple projects

Tags: tags

I am developing a Linux kernel driver so I have a git directory with my project.
I have another git directory with the Linux sources.
I am using neovim with gutentags with the setting of `gtags_cscope` as the `gutentags_modules`.
My cache dir is `.cache/vim`.  gtag-cscope generates different tag directories for each of the projects.
When I edit a file in my driver project and try to jump to the definition of a kernel function I see that the symbol is not found.  However if I edit a file in the Linux kernel directory and try to jump to the definition of kernel function the symbol is found.

So it seems that gutentags or gtag-cscope **cannot** search in multiple tag directories.  Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

Vim is able to query tags from multiple projects and usually all you need to do is set the [`'tags'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tags%27) option to point to the `tags` files in each directory.

In `'nocompatible'` mode (which is the default), [`'tagrelative'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tagrelative%27) defaults to "on", which means when Vim finds the tag in a `tags` file in another directory (a tag belonging to the other project), it will look up the file name relative to the directory where that `tags` file is, rather than the current directory.

So you could also look up tags from the Linux kernel source tree using:

```
set tags+=/path/to/src/linux/tags
```

Assuming `/path/to/src/linux` is the directory where your Linux kernel source tree lives, and that you have successfully created a `tags` file there. You can do so by changing to that top directory and running `ctags -R .` (but the exact details might depend on which version of the "ctags" program you have in your system.)

I'm not really sure how plug-ins such as "gutentags" or "gtag-cscope" will interact with these settings. My understanding is that they're mostly concerned with keeping the `tags` file up to date, by invoking `ctags` in background after you modify local files, so I think it's quite reasonable that they'll just leave your addition to the `'tags'` option alone, so it's quite possible everything will just keep working even in the presence of such plug-ins. So I'd suggest you just go ahead and try it, see if it works, it's likely that it will.

Comment: It does not help as it only shares the ctags files.  I need to share the directories with the GPATH, GRTAGS & GTAGS of the two projects so I can do find all references of a symbol